# python doesn't connect to discord token

Tags: python, discord

So I am very much a newbie, I am trying to connect a discord bot to python. I've followed multiple tutorials  but all of them result in the same problem:

```
TOKEN = (<the token I am using>)
NameError: name '<the token I am using>' is not defined
```

I am not sure what is wrong? I am on Mac and using PyCharm CE.

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
client = discord.Client()
TOKEN = (my token)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be displaying properly, could you edit your question to include the example?

Comment: is the token value in the form of a string? that means, is it  of the form `TOKEN = "198249184AB8"` or is it `TOKEN = 198249184AB8`. Notice the missing quotes in the second option. The ideal way is for it to be like the first one. I would suggest you to include the token (replace all alphabets with another alphabet and numbers with some other number for security)

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite unclear, however, python NameError is usually caused by:

> Misspelled Variable or Function Name

So you probably didn't put quotes around the token itself to make it a string or something as simple as that.

Comment: fixed the post so it now includes the code. And yeah I am stupid and didn't put quotes around the token ty, however there's now a new problem: 

```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file name", line 936, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
```
I don't have 936 lines and there are like 20 of these error messages? What is wrong? sorry to be a bother.

Answer (score 0):

The token value needs to be in the form of a string. That means, it is of the form

```
TOKEN = "198249184AB8"
```

Notice the quotes around the value.